# Pixel Coordinates of Image with Python

Tags: python, image

I need to get Pixel coordinates of an image. Here is explanation:
[image]

In the Image Editor, I can see the coordinates in the bottom left corner by clicking on the image. Is it possible to get the coordinates with Python? Solution for this question [Pixel Coordinates of Rendered Image with Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14941/pixel-coordinates-of-rendered-image-with-python) doesn't help, because it works only for rendered image and I need this for any image.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your workflow is going to look like. Are you importing external images first?

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh yes, I just load image from file system. I am creating a tool that will add and move objects on image. For this I need to get coordinates of mouse pointer on image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eeeeeeh… [that answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14941/pixel-coordinates-of-rendered-image-with-python) sounds horribly complicated to me!

Assuming you are getting mouse coordinates from event `e` (from invoke or modal callbacks of an operator), and assuming that operator runs into the main (`'WINDOW'` type) region of the `UVEditor` space, something like that should work (code *not* tested):

```
region = C.region
reg_x, reg_y = e.mouse_region_x, e.mouse_region_y
img_size = C.space.image.size

uv_x, uv_y = region.view2d.region_to_view(reg_x, reg_y)

img_x, img_y = uv_x * img_size[0], uvèy * img_size[1]
```