# Getting pixel rgb values of background image in blender

Tags: python

I need to know the blender python script to read rgb colour values on a background image on screen (the image used as aid in 3d modelling) or just to read rgb values from whatever is rendered on screen at a specific x,y position, assuming the background image is included. The aim is to create a script that auto-positions mesh vertices according to the bg image as if modelling from bg image but automatically.

Comment: Some useful links, get pixel coord of view http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/get-location-in-scene-for-pixel?rq=1  get the rgb value of a pixel http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53780/pixel-coordinates-of-image-with-python?rq=1